# Http Get request authorization in Angular

Tags: angular, http, get, http-get

I am using an API that gives me names and statistics for NBA players.
I have the following code that leads me to a 401 error (unauthorized).

```
constructor (private http: Http) {}
fullName;

getPlayerName() {
    this.http.get('https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nba/2016-2017-regular/cumulative_player_stats.json?playerstats=2PA,2PM,3PA,3PM,FTA,FTM').subscribe(data => {
        this.newdata= data.json()
        console.log(this.newdata)
this.fullName = data.json().cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry[0].player.FirstName + " " + data.json().cumulativeplayerstats.playerstatsentry[0].player.LastName
}
}
```

How can I add the username and password for authentication?

Comment: I don't think authentication works by providing a username and password each time you make a call. Do you know how this API provides authorization? Does it use cookies or JWT, for example?

Comment: I am not sure...if you visit the link I provided, a prompt asks you for the username and password. I have an account, I just need to provide angular my username and password.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You should read the documentation of this API (if one exists) to understand how it provides authorization. An API asking for password every time is nonsensical. You see this prompt when you visit the page with the browser, but when you make an XHR call from your app, you need to provide credentials, a token inside your request's headers, for example

Comment: Ok lets say I got the token... where in the code would I provide the credentials?

Comment: maybe this could help https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/data-feeds/api-docs/#

Comment: I don't know for sure, again, refer to a documentation of the API, but most sensible guess would be a header. So refer to the only answer

Comment: The API documentation says I must provide a http header where I will put the username and password of my account. I am not sure how to make the header however.

Comment: There is already an answer explaining where to put the headers

Answer (score 1):

You should set http headers like this example

```
let headers = new Headers(); headers.append('encrypted_credentials', username + ":" + password);
```

this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => { });

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#headers

```
One common task is adding an Authorization header to outgoing requests. Here's how you do that:


http
  .post('/api/items/add', body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),
  })
  .subscribe();
```

The HttpHeaders class is immutable, so every set() returns a new instance and applies the changes.

Comment: What do you mean "the bracket is not closed"?

Comment: Sorry my mistake It does get closed. however I am not sure where this code goes. Also I am getting a number of errors in my text editor when I insert the code... such as "cannot find name HttpHeaders".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
this.http.get('https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nba/2016-2017-regular/cumulative_player_stats.json?playerstats=2PA,2PM,3PA,3PM,FTA,FTM', {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('username', myUsername).set('password', myPassword)}).subscribe(// handle Result)
```